# In Civ 5 vanilla, If some city states enter permanent war, is diplomatic victory impossible?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm playing a Civ 5 game on a huge map. There are 24 city states and 8 other civs. I conquered 2 of them to obtain their luxuries, and 9 of the remaining city states have entered "permanent war".

I'm pretty sure a "permanent war" city state will always vote against me, so those are out. I have 3 questions about a diplomatic victory from this position:

1 - If I eliminate "permanent war" city states, will other city states join "permanent war"?

2 - If I conquer "permanent war" city states, and then they are liberated, will they still be on "permanent war"?

3 - How many votes are needed on the largest map size? I'm pretty sure my teammate and I can bribe all of the other city states and get their votes.

Comment: Great question! How did you end up in permanent war, and how many city states declared it? The only time that happened to me, *every* city state declared PM on me.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not impossible.

Every world leader election, the highest-voted civs get additional delegates. Thus, if you can stay at the top, and nobody achieves a different victory condition, you will eventually have enough votes to win.